# Error #1009 when creating objects or arrays

Tags: actionscript-3

I get this error when i test my movie: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

My code is:

```
var pieceArr:Array = new Array();
pieceArr[1] = {
    piece: MovieClip(wRook1.mc),
    x: 34,
    y: 526
}

var wRook1:Object = new Object();
wRook1.mc = new WhiteRook();
addChild(wRook1.mc);
wRook1.mc.x = pieceArr[1].x;
wRook1.mc.y = pieceArr[1].y;
wRook1.inPeace = "a1";
```

I tried to using object instead of array but i got the same error.

Comment: If the code in the question is correct, aren't you assigning the [1] element *after* you try to access it?

Comment: thanks for the answer. i guessed flash is asynchronous.

Comment: No, it isn't. It's a normal programming language that semantically executes things in the top-to-bottom order. In other words, you're trying to read out the contents of that array, and then later on (further down) you set that array to a new array object. So, at the time you're reading the array, it has not been set yet, hence, `null`.

Comment: it s still giving error even i put the array code to the top.,

Comment: The same error? Either way, edit your question with the new content so that people can see exactly what you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the `pieceArr` Array before you created it. Therefore when you try to set `wRook1.mc.x` and `wRook1.mc.y` you're trying to get something that doesn't exists yet. You'll have to change the order of your code to something like this:

```
var wRook1:Object = new Object();
wRook1.mc = new WhiteRook();
addChild(wRook1.mc);

wRook1.inPeace = "a1";

var pieceArr:Array = new Array();
pieceArr[1] = 
{
    // can't reference wRook1.mc before it's created
    piece: MovieClip(wRook1.mc),
    x: 34,
    y: 526
}

// can't reference pieceArr before it's created
wRook1.mc.x = pieceArr[1].x;
wRook1.mc.y = pieceArr[1].y;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `pieceArr` is not defined.

Also (even if you had defined `pieceArr` earlier, `pieceArr[1]` does not exist. Note that you haven't yet assigned anything to `pieceArr[1]` before you try to acces its `x` and `y`.

This code will work perfectly.

```
var pieceArr:Array = new Array();
pieceArr[1] = {
        piece: null,
        x: 34,
        y: 526
}

var wRook1:Object = new Object();
wRook1.mc = new WhiteRook();
addChild(wRook1.mc);
pieceArr[1].piece = wRook1.mc;
wRook1.mc.x = pieceArr[1].x;
wRook1.mc.y = pieceArr[1].y;
wRook1.inPeace = "a1";
```